# Ubuntu 16.04 change splash screen

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, splash

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to change the splash screen.

I have already changed the text "Ubuntu 16.04" by editing the file /usr/share/plymouth/themes/text.plymouth as shown below:

```
[ubuntu-text]
title=Custom_Title
black=0x2c001e
white=0xffffff
brown=0xff4012
blue=0x988592
```

However, changing the colour values does not affect the background colour etc.

I would like a blue background with yellow text and I would also like to change the loading dot colours.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /path/to/theme/folder/theme.plymouth 100

$ sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

(select theme desired)

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

... and reboot!

you don't need edit any file